# In Oracle, can we restore a database onto the same instance with a different name?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, restore, feature-comparison

In SQL server I can restore a database onto the same instance with a different name. Eg: If there is a database DB_prod, I can take a full backup and restore it on the same instance with a different name like DB_test.

Is a similar task possible with Oracle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easily - just use RMAN to [clone](http://blogs.oracle.com/AlejandroVargas/2007/02/how_to_manually_clone_a_databa.html) it. I think you mean in Oracle terminology, clone the database into a new instance on the same server. If you really do mean clone the *schema* into the same Oracle instance, then the easiest way is [Datapump](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Data+Pump+Export+%28expdp%29+and+Data+Pump+Import%28impdp%29).

Comment: So I will need to clone the schema to the same instance. Having the right terminology make the difference .Thanks Gaius.

Answer (score 3):

Gaius has the correct answer<sup>+1</sup>. You should consider virtualizing the server to run both the original and the clone in separate virtual machines.  It makes the setup of the clone considerably simpler and can help with managing the priorities between the two instances.  If that is not possible and you are on 11.2+ you should look at [instance caging](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10595/dbrm007.htm).

Comment: Instance caging, that is something new. Let me have a look into. Thanks Leigh.